# How to align text to TOP in a tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want for the text in my entry widget to start appearing at the top as if it was top justified. With `tkinter.Entry`'s justify option you can justify the text to the left, right or center, but not top or bottom. Specifically, I would like to have an option to do the function of the highlighted button below in google docs.

[image]

Comment: An `Entry` only supports a single line of text; there are no options for vertical positioning within it.  Unless you're doing something very weird with the widget's geometry, there shouldn't even be any room to move the text vertically without clipping it.

Comment: Thank you. that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An entry widget only accepts a single line of text. There is no concept of vertical alignment in an Entry widget.

The `Text` widget supports multiple lines, but it also doesn't have any support for vertical alignment.